# Loop Through Excel Files and See if a Specific Cell Is Blank

Tags: excel, vba

I inherited VBA code that has not worked since my work updated our version of Excel.

The original code looped through all Excel files in a specific folder.
If data in specific cells was blank or a 0, would rename the whole workbook so I would know what files to delete after the fact.

This is the original code. I don't need it to do all of this anymore.

This is part one:

```vb
Sub AllFilesWeekly()
    Dim folderPath As String
    Dim filename As String
    Dim wb As Workbook
  
    folderPath = "C:\Users\" & (Environ$("Username")) & "\Desktop\Process Production\" 'change to suit
    
    If Right(folderPath, 1) <> "\" Then folderPath = folderPath + "\"
    
    filename = Dir(folderPath & "*.xlsx")
    Do While filename <> ""
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        Set wb = Workbooks.Open(folderPath & filename)
         
        'Call a subroutine here to operate on the just-opened workbook
        Call getmetrics
        On Error Resume Next
        If Not ActiveWorkbook.Name Like "Audit Hub Report Distribution*" Then
            ActiveWorkbook.Close
        End If
        filename = Dir
    Loop
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

The second part:

```vb
Sub getmetrics()
Dim cell As Range
Dim procstring As String, wbname As String
'Dim OQAYTD As String
Dim OQAMTD As String
Dim ORLYTD As String
Dim ORLMTD As String
Dim DR As String
Dim Audits As Long
Dim permonth As String, peryear As String, permonthrl As String, peryearrl As String
Dim RS As Worksheet, AD As Worksheet, QD As Worksheet, ws As Worksheet, YN As Boolean

For Each ws In Worksheets
    If ws.Name = "Audit Detail" Then
        YN = True
    End If
Next ws

If YN = True Then
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(2).Name = ("Rep Summary")

    Set RS = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Rep Summary")
    Set AD = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Audit Detail")
    Set QD = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Question Detail")

    With Sheets("Process Summary")
        For Each cell In Range(Range("A3"), Range("A9999").End(xlUp))
            If cell.Value = "Record Level YTD" Then
                ORLYTD = Range(cell.Address).Offset(0, 1).Value
            Else
                If cell.Value = "YTD Quality Average" Then
                    OQAYTD = Range(cell.Address).Offset(0, 1).Value
                Else
                    If cell.Value = "Record Level Quality Average" Then
                        ORLMTD = Range(cell.Address).Offset(0, 1).Value
                    Else
                        If cell.Value = "Quality Average" Then
                            OQAMTD = Range(cell.Address).Offset(0, 1).Value
                        Else
                            If cell.Value = "Audits" Then
                                Audits = Range(cell.Address).Offset(0, 1).Value
                            End If
                        End If
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        Next cell
    End With

    wbname = Left(ActiveWorkbook.Name, Len(ActiveWorkbook.Name) - 4)
    peryear = VBA.Format(OQAYTD, "Percent")
    permonth = VBA.Format(OQAMTD, "Percent")
    peryearrl = VBA.Format(ORLYTD, "Percent")
    permonthrl = VBA.Format(ORLMTD, "Percent")
    DR = Right(Sheets("Process Summary").Range("A2").Value, Len(Sheets("Process 
Summary").Range("A2").Value) - 12)

    RS.Range(RS.Range("A1"), RS.Range("IV1").End(xlToLeft)).AutoFilter
    RS.Range(RS.Range("A1"), RS.Range("IV1").End(xlToLeft)).EntireColumn.AutoFit
    AD.Range(AD.Range("A1"), AD.Range("IV1").End(xlToLeft)).AutoFilter
    AD.Range(AD.Range("A1"), AD.Range("IV1").End(xlToLeft)).EntireColumn.AutoFit
    QD.Range(QD.Range("A1"), QD.Range("IV1").End(xlToLeft)).AutoFilter
    QD.Range(QD.Range("A1"), QD.Range("IV1").End(xlToLeft)).EntireColumn.AutoFit

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    procstring = wbname & "|" & permonth & "|" & Audits & "|" & peryear & "|" & permonthrl & "|" & 
    peryearrl & "|" & DR ' & "|" & Users
    Debug.Print procstring

Else
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Dim AWN As String
    AWN = ActiveWorkbook.FullName
    Debug.Print "Not Audited: " & ActiveWorkbook.Name
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs "C:\Users\" & (Environ$("Username")) & "\Desktop\Process Production\Delete -" & Second(Now)

    Kill AWN
    ActiveWorkbook.Close savechanges:=True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End If

End Sub
```

All I need to do is look at cell D3 on the "Process Summary" tab.
If the value in that space is "0.00%", rename the workbook to delete and loop on until all workbooks are looked at.
I do not need to screen print all the extra numbers any more.

Comment: "has not worked" is a little vague - what does it do or not do which is not what you need?   Also -can you fix the indenting in the second part?  It's pretty difficult to follow as posted.

Comment: FYI in part 2 you have `With Sheets("Process Summary")` but nothing inside that block references the `With`, so that would be one place to start looking.

Comment: I also would apply correct indenting to all the `IF`s. This might help as well. Regarding the second script: This code definitly never checks D3. Moreover it doesn't make sense to do all the changes on the sheets and then delete the workbook. Maybe two things got mixed up in the code? Maybe you should write one sub that really checks for D3 and then rename the file

Answer (score 0):

Build a [Collection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/concepts/collections) of filenames that match the criteria and then use it to rename the files.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub AllFilesWeekly()

    Dim folderPath As String, filename As String
    Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet
    Dim col As Collection, n As Long
    Set col = New Collection
  
    folderPath = "C:\Users\" & (Environ$("Username")) & "\Desktop\Process Production\" 'change to suit
    If Right(folderPath, 1) <> "\" Then folderPath = folderPath + "\"
    
    ' scan folder
    filename = Dir(folderPath & "*.xlsx")
    Do While filename <> ""
      
        Set wb = Workbooks.Open(folderPath & filename, True, True) ' update links, readonly
        For Each ws In wb.Sheets
           If ws.Name = "Process Summary" Then
               If Format(ws.Range("D3"), "0.00%") = "0.00%" Then
                  col.Add wb.Name
               End If
           End If
        Next
        wb.Close
        n = n + 1
        filename = Dir
    Loop

    ' result
    MsgBox "Files scanned =  " & n & vbCrLf & _
           "To delete = " & col.Count, vbInformation, folderPath

    ' rename
    If col.Count > 0 Then
         If MsgBox("Continue to rename ?", vbYesNo) = vbYes Then
             For n = 1 To col.Count
                Name folderPath & col(n) As folderPath & "delete_" & col(n)
             Next
             MsgBox "Rename done"
         End If
    End If
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this. It works perfectly and is helping me understand how VBA can work